# How can i reduce the space between list builder items?

Tags: flutter

I have created a ListView of RadioListTile and there is some intrinsic padding between the tiles which I am not able to remove. How can i fix this? Thanks in advance

My code:

```
 @override Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Column screen = Column(
        ....
        ,
        Expanded(
          child:
          ListView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            itemCount: tasks.length
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return RadioListTile<String>(
                    title:  Text(tasks[index], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
                    value: tasks[index],
                    groupValue: selectedRadio,
                    onChanged: (val){
                      setSelectedRadio(val);
                    }
                );          
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );

    return Scaffold(
      body: screen,
    );
  }
```

Comment: could you specify which padding ?

Comment: You need to use Radio in order to remove padding

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ListTileTheme` widget to remove the `padding` and set a vertically `dense` layout.

```
    ListTileTheme.merge(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              dense: true,
              child: ListView.builder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                itemCount: 7,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return RadioListTile<String>(
                       ...
                      });
                },
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Not working with RadioListTile, In this case, need to use Radio widget to remove the padding.